# Apache Felix: inherit import package org.osgi.service.cm

Tags: osgi, classnotfoundexception, apache-felix

I have one bundle which has Import-Package `org.osgi.service.cm`. In this bundle there is only an interface `ConfigurationInterface`, that declares a couple of methods, one throws an `org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException`. This bundle exports only its own package, lets say `com.foo.bar.configuration`.

Then I have other API bundles that have an interface for the service, `ServiceInterface`, that extends `ConfigurationInterface`, so they are importing the package `com.foo.bar.configuration`. Obviously there are also implementations bundle for these api that implement `ServiceInterface`, so they are importing `org.osgi.service.cm` because every implementations need to have the method that throws an `org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException`.

Everything is working fine, the problems come out when I declare these services as optional, because when they are not available the framework tries to instantiate a proxy from the interface and I get a  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException`. The framework suggests to add an import for 'org.osgi.service.cm' to the API bundle.

Is there a way to make this import available from the configuration bundle so that it is not necessary to add the import to every API?

Comment: "because when they are not available the framework tries to instantiate a proxy from the interface...": Just a piece of advice: Do not use any technology that does such "magic". Magic is the holy grail of half professional programmers. While it looks cool, it is evil, especially in the OSGi world.

Comment: Which framework do you refer to? Felix or something else?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing package imports/exports and services / components? The first two paragraphs are about the former, while in the third paragraph you write "the framework tries to instantiate a proxy from the interface", which sounds like dependency injection from some component framework.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I'm using Felix.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos I don't think to use any "magic" technologies, I'm referring to the part of the felix framework that instantiates a null object for unavailable services. For the moment I added the import of org.osgi.service.cm to every api bundles and it works

Comment: I think adding the import to every bundle that needs it is the only way to go.